# Validate Connection fail to publish asp.net website to docker on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, docker

I have successfully setup docker on ubuntu and try to publish my asp.net 5 follow this instruction https://blog.robseder.com/2015/05/03/docker-deploying-an-asp-net-5-app-to-run-on-ubuntu-linux-server/

But the connection always fail to authenticate as the image below.

[image]

I'm using ip address instead of server name. Please see image below for my server ip address.

[image]

I'm not sure that I'm using the right ip address or does it need any special configure on server to get it work?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?